# Change scheme using fiddler

Tags: http, https, fiddler

I am using fiddler as reverse proxy, my query is how we can change the https request to http using fiddler. I am trying to create a rule which can change the incoming request which is https and return as http.

Is this possible by editing rules in fiddler? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say what you tried already? It's not clear what you mean by "return as HTTP"-- a HTTPS request can be easily routed to a HTTP endpoint, but when the client gets the response, it's going to be over HTTPS.

You can easily change the scheme of a request:

```
if (!oSession.isHTTPS && !oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT") && 
    oSession.HostnameIs("myServer")) 
{
  oSession.oRequest.headers.UriScheme = "https";
}
```

I assume you've already figured out how to get Fiddler to act as a reverse proxy for HTTPS. It's non-obvious, but well-covered in the new Fiddler book.